# r nested for loop with if statement error message

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

here the input data and my expectations (y).

```
# input:
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(1:10, ncol = 2))
x=c(1.5, 2.8, 4.1)
y=c(0, 0, 0)
mydf
x
y

# code
for (i in 1:(length(x))
    for (j in 2:(dim(mydf)[1])
    {{
        if (x[i])>mydf[(j-1),1]) & (x[i])<mydf[j,1]) 
            {y[i]<-mydf[(j-1),2]} 
        else {y[i]<-9999999999}
    }}
y
```

expectation for y: 6,7,9. I do not understand the error.

Comment: You need to place the opening and closing brackets in the right position. That is, `for(condition){dostuff}`. The same goes for if-statements. And for-loops are not really needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that will work and give your expected output :

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    for (j in 2:nrow(mydf)) {
        if (mydf[j-1,1] < x[i] & x[i] < mydf[j,1]) {
            y[i] <- mydf[j-1,2]    
            break
        } else {y[i]<-9999999999}
    }
}

y

[1] 6 7 9
```

You need to add the `break` otherwise `j` will keep looping and return 9999999999.

A more elegant option would be this :

```
x=c(1.5, 2.8, 4.1,11)
mydf[nrow(mydf),2]<-999999 # y can't be equal to the lower right cell, so I transform it
y<-mydf[findInterval(x,mydf[,1]),2]
y

y
[1]      6      7      9 999999
```

An other solution would be this (it is best if some values will return 9999) :

```
x<-c(-3,1.5, 2.8, 4.1,11)
temp<-sapply(x,function(z){z>mydf[,1]&z<mydf[-1,1]})
temp2<-sapply(seq_along(x),function(z){match(TRUE,temp[,z])})
y<-mydf[temp2,2]
y[is.na(y)]<-9999
y

[1] 9999    6    7    9 9999
```